# Does installing a .deb or .rpm package always add a repository to one's system?

Tags: software-installation, package-management, rpm, repository, deb

Installing Google's .deb or .rpm Chrome package adds the Google repository to one's system for automatic updates. Does installing a .deb or .rpm package always add a repository to one's system? If not, how does one verify whether a package will add a repository when installed?

Comment: No. It only does if the vendor designs the package to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The only method I'm aware of is to interrogate the package looking for repository files.

#### Example

With RPMs you can interrogate a package like so:

```
$ rpm -ql rpmfusion-free-release-19-1.noarch | grep yum.repos.d
/etc/yum.repos.d/rpmfusion-free-rawhide.repo
/etc/yum.repos.d/rpmfusion-free-updates-testing.repo
/etc/yum.repos.d/rpmfusion-free-updates.repo
/etc/yum.repos.d/rpmfusion-free.repo
```

Any time you see files that are targeting the location `/etc/yum.repos.d` then a repository is included within the RPM.

For DEB files it's a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

No, not necessarily.

There is no easy way to test. You can download the rpm/deb, extract the contents of the rpm/deb and look for any files that will be added to the repolist of the system, or look for any scripts included in the package that will do the same.

To extract contents from a rpm

```
rpm2cpio anyrpmfile.rpm | cpio -midv
```

To extract contents from a deb

```
ar p mypackage.deb data.tar.gz | tar zx
```

You can also list the contents of a rpm/deb file without extracting and installing it

```
rpm -qpl rpmfile.rpm
dpkg --contents debfile.deb
```